# NumPy apply along axis specifying function for each subtensor?

Tags: python, numpy

Say there's a matrix `A` of shape `(N, M)` and some `dtype`. Then, there is a vector of `numpy` functions `B` of shape `(N, )`. Since it might matter, for my specific case, `N` ranges in thousands (e.g. 4000) and `M` ranges in units (e.g. 9).

Example (`N=5`,`M=3`):

```
A =
[
    [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
    [4.02, 123.4, 534.65],
    [2.32, 22.0, 754.01],
    [5.41, 23.1, 1245.5],
    [6.07, 0.65, 22.12],
]

B = [
    np.min,
    np.max,
    np.argmin,
    np.argmin,
    np.min
]
```

`B[i]` will always be either `np.min`, `np.max`, `np.argmin` or `np.argmax`.

I'd like to perform operations on `axis=1`, and specifically the operation `B[i]` on `A[i, :]`, producing this output:

```
[ 0.1, 534.65, 0, 0, 0.65 ]
```

Is something like this achievable in NumPy?

A possible solution would be to split `A` according to equivalence groups on `B`, apply individual operations along `axis=1`, reindex the groups and merge them back, but that sounds very inefficient. I'd like to avoid that if possible.

If what I'm proposing sounds ridiculous to you, let me know.

Comment: If you care about efficiency it matters whether the amount of functions is small compared to the number of columns in A. So is it?

Comment: The result you proposed is applied along `axis=0` (row-wise)

Comment: It's either that or a simple iteration on `zip(A,B)`.  `B` is object dtype, essentially a list.

Comment: @user2640045 Sorry, I should've added that info in. `N >> M`. `N` is in the thousands, `M` in the units.

Comment: @SamarthBhatia The result I shown you as an example is actually applied along `axis=1`. The first axis are the rows, the second axis are the columns.

Comment: Note axes are 0 and 1 which correspond to rows and columns; maybe you were thinking 1 and 2 so 1 corresponds to rows.

Comment: @SamarthBhatia No, I was thinking correctly. It's okay though, axes can be confusing.

Comment: @SamarthBhatia When an operation is applied along a specific axis, then that is the axis for which the index varies with respect to a single units in the operation, and all other axes (orthogonal) are constant for each single unit. For example, if you had a tensor of rank 3, then applying along `axis=0` would yield elements `[:, 0, 0]`, `[:, 0, 1]`, `...`, `[:, 1, 0]`, `[:, 1, 1]` etc. Just like in my example, applying along `axis=1` yields elements `[0, :]`, `[1, :]`, etc. which are what I refer to as `rows` in `A`, as those are the sublists inside the large list called `A`.

Answer (score 2):

Why is this not feasible for you? :

```
A = np.array(A) # A originally is what you have given
B = [...] # what you have given

for i in range(len(B)):
    print( np.apply_along_axis(B[i], 0, A[i,:]) )
```

**Note**: It is faster than doing `B[i](A[i,:])` recursively.
Check this [link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) (it's the `numpy` documentation)

Comment: what does `apply_along_axis` add?  `B[i](A[i])` is simpler.

Comment: @hpaulj I have edited my answer to include a reference from the numpy docs

Comment: Wouldn't this be very inefficient? You're using a for loop to call all of those functions separately.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan `np.apply_over_axes` exists, which applies **a** function over all axes. However, I don't know how you can do this with a list of functions.

Comment: `apply_over_axis` and `apply_over_axes` are equivalent when considering a single axis.

Comment: Note it is `apply_along_axis` for a 1d implementation and `apply_over_axes` would not require you to loop through a list of functions because it takes only one function.
View the documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html#numpy-apply-over-axes)

Comment: @SamarthBhatia Actually, both `aai` and `aae` take a single function as a parameter to apply.

Comment: And that is why we are looping over the list of functions for `aai`. Also, try this with `axis=1` that you won't shut up about. `numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1`

Comment: `apply_along...` over states its speed.  I'd suggest actual time tests.

Comment: @SamarthBhatia Well of course your code throws an error for `axis=1`. `A[i, :]` is a single vector! It only has a single axis. When I was saying that I want to apply the operation along `axis=1`, I was talking about my original matrix `A`, not its rows taken as individual subtensors.

Comment: @SamarthBhatia And again, as I said, I am looking for a solution which does not use loops. Loops are to be avoided when using `numpy`, we don't use `numpy` for clean code :) If noone can think of such solution, I will fallback to the solution proposed by myself.

Comment: @SamarthBhatia Another note, `aai(e)` for builtin `numpy` functions makes no sense. You can just take the function and call it instead of supplying it to another function. So, instead, you could simply just do `B[i](A[i,:])` and save time. Thanks for trying to answer my question though!

Comment: Yes, I guess I didn't consider that!

Answer (score 1):

Your 2 lists:

```
In [162]: A =[
     ...:     [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
     ...:     [4.02, 123.4, 534.65],
     ...:     [2.32, 22.0, 754.01],
     ...:     [5.41, 23.1, 1245.5],
     ...:     [6.07, 0.65, 22.12],
     ...: ]
     ...: 
     ...: B = [
     ...:     np.min,
     ...:     np.max,
     ...:     np.argmin,
     ...:     np.argmin,
     ...:     np.min
     ...: ]
```

The straightforward list comprehension:

```
In [164]: [b(a) for b,a in zip(B,A)]
Out[164]: [0.1, 534.65, 0, 0, 0.65]
```

Note that the list elements are a mix of float and int, values and indices.

```
In [165]: timeit [b(a) for b,a in zip(B,A)]
61.1 µs ± 918 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Making `A` an array before hand helps.  Making `B` an array (object dtype) does not help:

```
In [167]: %%timeit A1=np.array(A)
     ...: [b(a) for b,a in zip(B,A1)]
35.6 µs ± 36.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Regarding your idea of collecting like valued functions in `B`, here's a start:

Skipping the logic of collecting like elements of `B`, these are the groups:

```
In [169]: idx = [[0,4],[1],[2,3]]
In [171]: arr = np.array(A)       # has to be array for multirow indexing
In [172]: [B[i[0]](arr[i], axis=1) for i in idx]
Out[172]: [array([0.1 , 0.65]), array([534.65]), array([0, 0])]
In [173]: timeit [B[i[0]](arr[i], axis=1) for i in idx]
49.2 µs ± 1.79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Not faster here, but for a large array with many repeats it might save some time.

To rebuild the ordered list, change it to a loop with assignment to an object dtype array:

```
In [181]: res = np.empty(len(B), object)
     ...: for i in idx:
     ...:     res[i] = B[i[0]](arr[i], axis=1)
     ...: 
In [182]: res
Out[182]: array([0.1, 534.65, 0, 0, 0.65], dtype=object)
In [183]: %%timeit
     ...: res = np.empty(len(B), object)
     ...: for i in idx:
     ...:     res[i] = B[i[0]](arr[i], axis=1)
     ...: 
71.5 µs ± 48 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

One way to collect like `B` elements is to use a `dict`:

```
In [185]: dd = defaultdict(list)
In [186]: for i,b in enumerate(B): dd[b].append(i)
...
In [189]: list(dd.values())
Out[189]: [[0, 4], [1], [2, 3]]
In [190]: res = np.empty(len(B), object)
     ...: for k in dd:
     ...:     i = dd[k]
     ...:     res[i] = k(arr[i], axis=1)
     ...: 
In [191]: res
Out[191]: array([0.1, 534.65, 0, 0, 0.65], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! Sorry if this comes up ungrateful, but the benchmark is kind of out of place here. It is true that I posted precisely these examples of `A` and `B`, but I also mentioned that `N` is very large, much larger than `M` and definitely much larger than 5. I assume the differences in performance would be much more apparent, since I cannot base anything on these inconclusive results. +1 for the effort, but I cannot accept this, as your only contribution is the benchmark of already proposed solutions, which unfortunately is for too small values of `N`.

Comment: I leave the real world benchmarking to you.  There are too many variables - both dimensions of A, the duplicates of B etc.  Grouping, on the surface is more work, but could be a time saver. Maybe by a factor of 2, but I doubt much more.  But why mix actions like this in first place?  Just apply `min` to one array of values, aargmax to another etc.  There's something artificial about that `B` list.

Comment: You can check out my own answer if you're interested. The factor actually tends to something slightly above `8` and stays between `7` and `8` for my purposes. And of course, you're right that the use case is hard to imagine, but the true motivation for this is a) generalization and b) reinforcement learning tricks. For example, I have a full array of computed `Q-values` but need their `max` or `min` w.r.t. `axis=1` according to whether the current player (given by `B` or something mappable 1:1 to `B`) was white or black.

Comment: What I actually did is separating the `min`/`max` and `argmin`/`argmax`, as I secretly knew that `B` would never contain `foo` and `argfoo` at the same time, and just multiplied `A[i]` by `-1` whenever `B[i]` was `(arg)min`, then called `(arg)max` on the whole thing, and changed the signs back. When I realized I could do this, this question became somewhat philosophical :D I hope you had fun, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the benchmarking done by @hpaulj, I've created this script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import perf_counter_ns

COUNT = 100
M = 9

x = []
y_1 = []
y_2 = []

fns = [np.min, np.max, np.argmin, np.argmax]

for n in range(2, 200, 1):
    print(n)
    A = np.random.rand(n, M)
    B = np.random.choice(fns, n)

    x.append(n)

    y1acc = []
    y2acc = []

    for i in range(COUNT):
        start = perf_counter_ns()
        res1 = [b(a) for b, a in zip(B, A)]
        y1acc.append(perf_counter_ns() - start)

        start = perf_counter_ns()
        groups = {fn: [] for fn in fns}

        for j, fn in enumerate(B):
            groups[fn].append(j)

        res2 = np.empty(n, object)

        for fn, indices in groups.items():
            res2[indices] = fn(A[indices], axis=1)

        y2acc.append(perf_counter_ns() - start)

        assert np.array_equal(res1, res2)

    y_1.append(sum(y1acc) / COUNT)
    y_2.append(sum(y2acc) / COUNT)

plt.plot(x, y_1, label="zip")
plt.plot(x, y_2, label="groups")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

and observed these results:

[image: 2 - 200]

Clearly, the overhead for splitting and merging the minuscule array was way larger than the NumPy speedup resulting from `O(1)` calls of `np.foo` instead of `O(N)`.

For larger N (`for n in range(100, 5000, 100)`):

[image: 100 - 5000]

we clearly observe the linear behavior expected from performing these operations, however, the constant in the splitting-merging approach is much smaller. Please note that this benchmark was not performed under controlled conditions, but the introduced noise is negligible.